# How can I change the tree's color?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jqtree

Well, I "created" a little tree with two parents and three children using [JqTree](http://mbraak.github.io/jqTree/#general), and now I would like to change the properties of it, such as color, border and so on, but I do not want to change the library. Can you help me?

Thanks in advance.

```js
var ExampleData = {};

ExampleData.data = [{
  label: 'node1',
  id: 1,
  children: [{
    label: 'child1',
    id: 2
  }, {
    label: 'child2',
    id: 3
  }]
}, {
  label: 'node2',
  id: 4,
  children: [{
    label: 'child3',
    id: 5
  }]
}];

ExampleData.getFirstLevelData = function(nodes) {
  if (!nodes) {
    nodes = ExampleData.example_data;
  }

  var data = [];

  $.each(nodes, function() {
    var node = {
      label: this.label,
      id: this.id
    };

    if (this.children) {
      node.load_on_demand = true;
    }

    data.push(node);
  });

  return data;
}

ExampleData.getChildrenOfNode = function(node_id) {
  var result = null;

  function iterate(nodes) {
    $.each(nodes, function() {
      if (result) {
        return;
      } else {
        if (this.id == node_id) {
          result = this;
        }

        if (this.children) {
          iterate(this.children);
        }
      }
    });
  }

  iterate(ExampleData.example_data);

  return ExampleData.getFirstLevelData(result.children);
}

$('#tree1').tree({
  data: ExampleData.data,
  autoOpen: false,
  dragAndDrop: true

});
```

```css
  #navdata {

    width: auto;

    height: auto;

    flex: 1;

    padding-bottom: 1px;

  }

  #navgrid {

    width: 50%;

    height: 200px;

    overflow-x: visible;

    overflow-y: scroll;

    border: solid 1px #79B7E7;

    background-color: #DDEBF7;

  }

  #header {

    background-color: #79B7E7;

    width: 100%;

    text-align: center;

    border: 1px solid white;

  }

  #tree {

    background-color: #FF0000;

  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  

</head>

<body>
  <div id="navgrid">
    <div id="header">Header</div>
    <div id="tree1"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please do try to find the solution before pasting a question: https://github.com/mbraak/jqTree/issues/93 - if you did search and you tried things and they didn't work out, then write details about what you have tried and how it did not work out.

Comment: Thanks! I've searched for it, but I'm dumb so I searched for: "How to change css properties when using Libraries", I wish someday all the answers about programming will be here on StackOverflow.

Comment: I will reformulate my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add following css for jqTree

level 1 :

```
.jqtree-tree .jqtree-title .jqtree-title-folder {
    color: aqua !important;
}
```

level2 :

```
.jqtree-tree .jqtree-title {
    color: bisque !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, for sharing it +1, What is the title-folder? I've tested it, but nothing changed?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @risadinha for searching correctly, differently than what I did, at least the answer is going to be here now on StackOverflow.

```
var data = [
  {
    label: 'node1',
    id: 1,
    color: 'green'
  }
];
```

And on CSS:

```css
.jqtree-element {
  background-color: red;
}
```